# block entering a certain page with a pop up message

Tags: javascript, php

I have 2 pages in my website (pay.php & receipt.php). A user would go from pay page to receipt page in a normal flow. However, when a user that's already reached receipt tries to go back to pay page, it will show an unhandled exception error page (because some objects that were being used in pay page gets destroyed after receipt page is reached). I want it so that after a user reaches receipt page, when he/she tries to go back it shows a pop up saying you can't go back because the order's finished.

I searched through many forums but most of them give solutions in the form of disabling the back space key, which I don't think is a good idea for my website. Could anyone help with this?

Thank you

Comment: Just set a session variable in "receipt.php" that you check in "pay.php". If it is set, redirect somewhere else or display a message.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, would you mind giving me a little example? My attempts seem to keep generating 'session already set' error.

Comment: I would just redirect them from pay.php to receipt.php if the user has already completed the form and than just show a message on receipt.php in the form of: 'the form is already completed' but a bit more user friendly. Message boxes showing the user has done something wrong or disabling what the user expects to work seems as bad usability and might scare of your visitors (but I think you know that since you don't really like these options too). But I would advice to do some usability testing with your target audiance to test these different aproaches and see what suits them the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion. Set the headers in the pay.php script to force a full request when a user clicks the back button. Then you can just handle the missing objects in pay.php and redirect to an error page or whatever you want.

```
header("Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT');
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
```

Here's the link to a discussion about it on [ellis lab forums](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/220867/). I have not tested this approach personally, but it should be a viable option.